# Highcharts - add additional export options without losing default ones

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I'm trying to *add* an export-to-csv option to a Highcharts chart, without actually removing all the default options (print, PNG, JPG, PDF, SVG export). The solution offered in [Highcharts add export as csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6315842/highcharts-add-export-as-csv) results in the existing options being blown away, as does trying to use the Exporting class in DotNet.Highcharts. Is there a way to achieve this?

NB: I can see how to achieve what I want by editing exporting.js, but that's not a desirable way to go about it :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add the new item to the menu right after you define the chart:

```
Highcharts.getOptions().exporting.buttons.contextButton.menuItems.push({
    text: 'My new button',
    onclick: function () {
        alert('OK');
    }
});
```

This will keep the default items.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/3GNZC/

Comment: this adds the new option to all charts on the page. Is there any way to add new option to export menu of specific chart?

Comment: @Adnan, you can find the answer in this question: [Custom Highcharts Context Menu Button Appearing in Every Chart on Page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23944451/custom-highcharts-context-menu-button-appearing-in-every-chart-on-page)