# Custom Highcharts Context Menu Button Appearing in Every Chart on Page

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a page with several charts, and I need to be able to add specific options to the exporting context menu for each chart.  This is the code I am using:

```
myChart.options.exporting.buttons.contextButton.menuItems.push({
        text: "Custom Option",
        onclick: someFunction
    });
```

Unfortunately, this adds the option to every chart, not just the chart myChart references.  I'd like to be able to add an option and have it appear on only one chart.

Here is a fiddle which demonstrates: http://jsfiddle.net/4uP5y/2/

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To add button use options for chart. Then you can set for each chart different set of options: http://jsfiddle.net/4uP5y/4/

Get default buttons:

```
var buttons = Highcharts.getOptions().exporting.buttons.contextButton.menuItems;

buttons.push({
    text: "Tokyo Only Option",
    onclick: HelloWorld
});
```

And set them for a chart:

```
exporting: {
    buttons: {
        contextButton: {
            menuItems: buttons // or buttons.slice(0,6)
        }
    }
},
```

Comment: This is a bit subtle, but thanks, it works. The only way I could make it work is precisely as here: create an array with all buttons, then force it to render one fewer buttons on one of the charts.

You can't "just add a button to the one chart", you have to "just remove the buttons you don't want" from the one chart.

Comment: @philw Actually you can "just add a button to the one chart", see my answer above.

Answer (score 2):

Starting from Paweł Fus answer, I found out a cleaner solution for the general case. The main issue is you need not to mess around with original object and extend it. Instead, you'd be better cloning it. Please note that my solution requires jQuery.

```
function appendExportButton(mytext, myfunction){
  var defaultButtons = Highcharts.getOptions().exporting.buttons; // get default Highchart Export buttons
  var myButtons = $.extend(true, {}, defaultButtons);
  myButtons.contextButton.menuItems.push({
    text: mytext,
    onclick: myfunction
  });
  return {buttons: myButtons};
}
```

To insert this button in the desired chart, define the chart this way:

```
var mychart = new Highcharts.Chart({
  chart: {
    ...whatever...
  },
  plotOptions: {
    ...whatever...
  },
  series: {
    ...whatever...
  },
  exporting: appendExportButton("Save data in CSV format", saveCSV)
});
```

In the case of OP problem, this is the line you have to use:

```
exporting: appendExportButton("Tokyo Only Option", HelloWorld)
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KarmaProd/4uP5y/120/)

Comment: Thank! You save my day!

Answer (score 1):

See the updated fiddle with result : http://jsfiddle.net/4uP5y/3/

You just needed to mark the newYork chart with exporting enabled false, like this :

```
    exporting: {
        enabled: false
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found another possiblity to add it only to one chart. Add following to the chart where you want to extend the context menu

```
       exporting: {
            buttons: {
                contextButton: {
                    menuItems: [

                    ]
                }
            }
        },
```

.
Now you are able to extend the chart dynamicly with a method like

```
 function (button) {
    var userMenu = this.chart.userOptions.exporting.buttons.contextButton.menuItems;
    if (userMenu.length === 0) {
        var menuItems = Highcharts.getOptions().exporting.buttons.contextButton.menuItems;
        for (var itemIndex in menuItems) {
            userMenu.push(menuItems[itemIndex]);
        }
    }
    userMenu.push(button);
};
```

. Where this.chart points to the chart which context menu should be extended