# Added options in Highcharts download/context buttons get repeated

Tags: button, highcharts, download

I am adding a few options to my download/export/context buttons in Highcharts. However, the process is a bit complex, as this works as an API. A call is being received by one file, another file is being called where all the options for the graph is being produced, it comes back to the first file, where the graph is generated. Here, the additional options are introduced into the context buttons:

```
    function drawGraph(selectedID, selectedCountries, selectedYears, per_capita, graphBorder, graphSource, graphDefinition, graphStyle, graphXAxis, renderToGraph, renderToDescription)
    {
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            var options = {};               

            url = "xxx.com";

            jQuery.getJSON(url, {selectedCountries: selectedCountries , selectedID: selectedID, selectedYears: selectedYears, per_capita: per_capita, graphBorder: graphBorder, graphSource: graphSource, graphDefinition: graphDefinition, graphStyle: graphStyle, graphXAxis: graphXAxis, renderToGraph: renderToGraph, type: "jsonp"})
            .done(function(data)
            {
                //console.log(data);

                options.chart       = data["chart"];
                options.tooltip     = data["tooltip"];
                options.series      = data["series"];
                options.title       = data["title"];
                options.subtitle    = data["subtitle"];
                options.yAxis       = data["yAxis"];
                options.xAxis       = data["xAxis"];
                options.legend      = data["legend"];
                options.exporting   = data["exporting"];
                options.plotOptions = data["plotOptions"];
                options.credits     = data["credits"];

                if ((graphDefinition == "true") || (graphDefinition == "on"))
                {
                    jQuery('#'+renderToDescription).html(data["description"]);
                }

                var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);

            })


            var buttons = Highcharts.getOptions().exporting.buttons.contextButton.menuItems;                

            // add "separator line" 
            buttons.push({
                separator: true,
            });


            // add "Link to metadata"
            buttons.push({
                text: 'Metadata',
                onclick: function () {
                    window.open('http://xxx/metadata.php?selectedID=' + selectedID + '&selectedDatasettype=1', "_blank");
                }
            }); 
            }


            // add "separator line" 
            buttons.push({
                separator: true,
            });


            // add "Link to more data functions"
            buttons.push({
                text: 'Link to more data functions',
                onclick: function () {
                    window.open('http://xxx/options.php?selectedID=' + selectedID + '&selectedDatasettype=1', "_blank");
                }
            }); 
        });
    }
```

And from the other end, I have the file which generates the JSON code:

```
$data_ = array( "chart"         => array("renderTo" => $container, "type" => $graphStyle, "zoomType" => "xy", "marginTop" => $marginTop, "marginRight" => 20, "marginBottom" => 60, "marginLeft" => 80), 

                "title"         => array("useHTML" => true, "text" => "<div style='text-align: center'>".str_replace("CO2", "CO<sub>2</sub>", $selectedDataset -> name)."</div>", "align" => "center", "style" => array("fontFamily" => "Helvetica", "fontSize" => "20px")), 

                "subtitle"      => array("text" => "Original data source: <a href='" . $provider_url . "' style='font-family: Helvetica; color: #428bcc; text-decoration: none' target='_blank'>" . $selectedDataset -> data_provider . "</a>", "useHTML" => true), 

                "xAxis"         => array("tickWidth" => 0, "showFirstLabel" => true, "showLastLabel" => true, "tickInterval" => $step), 

                "yAxis"         => array("min" => $min, "title" => array("useHTML" => true, "text" => str_replace("CO2", "CO<sub>2</sub>", $yTitle), "fontWeight" => "bold", "align" => "high", "textAlign" => "left", "rotation" => 0, "y" => $yAxisY)), 

                "legend"        => array("enabled" => $flagValues, "layout" => "vertical", "align" => "center", "verticalAlign" => "middle", "backgroundColor" => "#efefef", "borderWidth" => 0, "floating" => false, "x" => -185, "y" => 100, "title" => array("text" => ":: Legend ::"), "floating" => true, "draggable" => true, "zIndex" => 20), 

                "plotOptions"   => array("series" => array("connectNulls" => true, "shadow" => false, "lineWidth" => 2, "marker" => array("enabled" => false))), 

                "tooltip"       => array("shared" => true, "crosshairs" => true), 

                "credits"       => array("text" => $copyright, "href" => "http://ede.grid.unep.ch", "position" => array("x" => 10, "y" => -20, "align" => "left"), "style" => array("fontSize" => "9px", "lineHeight" => "9px")), 

                "exporting"     => array("buttons" => array("contextButton" => array("symbol" => "url(http://geodata.grid.unep.ch/images/button_download_4.png)", "x" => -10, "y" => 10))),

                "series"        => $data,

                "protected"     => $selectedDataset -> protected_,

                "description"   => $selectedDataset -> abstract,

                "noData"        => $flagValues);

header("content-type: application/json"); 

echo $_GET['callback']. '('. json_encode($data_) . ')';
```

Now, strangely enough, it seems that if a user from the same site chooses one graph after another, the additional context items are being added up. So, the first call, the separator line and the link to metadata are being added; for the second call, I see the separator line and the link to metadata two times... Very strange. No clue. 
One thought: Can the contextButtons first be emptied for each call? And then the additional options added? Something like

```
Highcharts.getOptions().exporting.buttons.contextButton.menuItems.empty()
```

Thanks for any hints.

Comment: "chooses one graph after another"? What does this mean?

Comment: @Strand: It means that I call the website where the graph is being displayed, and then I choose another variable which the graph then displays. This second "load" or "call" to display the chart then, generates a dropdown list with two "Metadata" entries. See the screenshot.

Comment: [screenshot](http://de.tinypic.com/r/2w7h4sm/8).

Comment: That means you add `// add "separator line" ` and `// add "Link to metadata"` everytime you create new chart. That should happen only once.  Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23944451/custom-highcharts-context-menu-button-appearing-in-every-chart-on-page) question&answer will help you a bit?

Comment: @PawełFus: Thanks. Yes, this is indeed true. Unfortunately, the Q&A didn't really help. However, it gave me something to think about and to lots of tries. But still didn't find a solution. Best would be to be able to delete the two "pushs" and re-create them at each load. Anything like this possible?

Comment: Something is wrong here. Adding to `menuItems` should be done just one, for example when you load charts, you shouldn't add this lines for every chart - just once, when page is initially loaded. If you want to add for different charts separate items, then why don't you use [API](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#exporting.buttons.contextButton.menuItems) for that?

Comment: I edited the code above, so that it explains perhaps in more detail what I am fabricating there. The 'foreign' website includes the function-script in its code. From within that page then, a user can change variables in order to display graphs with different data. I still don't understand why these additional items get added up each time...

Comment: Try this: `var buttons = [];` and after adding to buttons array extra items: `options.exporting = { contextButton:{ menuItems: Highcharts.getOptions().exporting.buttons.contextButton.menuItems.concat(buttons) } };` - so avoid adding buttons directly to default options. Or as I said before, add items to `menuItems` **before** loading chart (not in the `drawGraph` function).

Comment: Thanks so much! Unfortunately, I am not sure about the first solution you offer. I put up a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/luftikus143/jz67utLz/1/). It would be great if you could correct what you have in your mind. -- The second option I do understand. However, the link to the external page has an ID, which for every graphic is different. And there, I don't really see how this ID could then be updated in the menuItems.

Comment: I am still struggling with this. Besides of the question if someone can clarify on the above suggestion of PawelFus, I wonder if a way could be to include the "Show Metadata" function in the [export-cvs.js](https://github.com/highslide-software/export-csv/blob/master/export-csv.js). But then, no idea how to recover the variable-ID from the main page in order to send the user to the right page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found an approach which seems to work well. This is, loop through the array of menuItems of the contextButton. Check if the item already exists, replace its function. Otherwise, use the standard push-option.

Hopes this helps someone else in a similar situation.

```
    var buttons = [];
    buttons = Highcharts.getOptions().exporting.buttons.contextButton.menuItems;

    flag_metadata = false;
    flag_link_functions = false;

    for (var x in Highcharts.getOptions().exporting.buttons.contextButton.menuItems) 
    {
        if (buttons[x].id == "Metadata")
        {
            buttons[x].onclick = function () {
                window.open('http://ede.grid.unep.ch/mod_metadata/metadata.php?selectedID=' + selectedID + '&selectedDatasettype=1', "_blank");}

            flag_metadata = true;
        }

        if (buttons[x].id == "Link")
        {
            buttons[x].onclick = function () {
                window.open('http://ede.grid.unep.ch/options.php?selectedID=' + selectedID + '&selectedDatasettype=1', "_blank");}

            flag_metadata = true;
        }
    }


    if (flag_metadata == false)
    {                                       
        // add "separator line" 
        Highcharts.getOptions().exporting.buttons.contextButton.menuItems.push({
            separator: true,
            id: 'sep1',
        });


        // add "Link to metadata"
        Highcharts.getOptions().exporting.buttons.contextButton.menuItems.push({
            id: 'Metadata',
            text: 'Metadata',
            onclick: function () {
                window.open('http://ede.grid.unep.ch/mod_metadata/metadata.php?selectedID=' + selectedID + '&selectedDatasettype=1', "_blank");
            }
        }); 


        // add "separator line" 
        Highcharts.getOptions().exporting.buttons.contextButton.menuItems.push({
            separator: true,
            id: 'sep2',
        });


        // add "Link to more data functions"
        Highcharts.getOptions().exporting.buttons.contextButton.menuItems.push({
            id: 'Link',
            text: 'Link to more data functions',
            onclick: function () {
                window.open('http://ede.grid.unep.ch/options.php?selectedID=' + selectedID + '&selectedDatasettype=1', "_blank");
            }
        }); 
    }
```